# autoGrantPermissions with Android device works on Windows, Linux, but not OSX

Tags: testing, appium

I'm using an Appium server to run tests on **physical** Android and iOS devices. At the moment the tests are very simple (using Appium through RobotFramework, with [RobotFramework-AppiumLibrary](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary)), and work well on both Windows and Linux computers.

I'm using the `autoGrantPermissions=true` Appium capabilities (see: [Appium Capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)) to ensure that no permission window makes the test suite fail. When running the test with a Windows/Linux Appium server, it works: the permissions pop-up never shows up.

When running the test with an OSX Appium server, it doesn't work. The permissions pop-up arises, and stops the whole test-suite.

I've tried adding the `autoAcceptAlerts` capability, but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `${ANDROID_HOME}/tools` and `${ANDROID_HOME}/platform_tools` weren't in the `PATH` environment variable.

Adding this to my `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` file fixed the issue:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform_tools"
```

Comment: Does autograntpermissions is fixed through this environment variable solution?